# Установка HTTP-статуса в экшне контроллера

Tags: php, yii2

Обычный `web`-контроллер (не `REST`).

```
if ($model->hasErrors()) {
    Yii::$app->getResponse()->setStatusCode(400);
}
```

В теле экшна почему-то не срабатывает.
Пример:

```
public function actionSave($model, $AJAXvalidate = false)
{
    $post = Yii::$app->request->post();
    if ($model->load($post) && $model->save()) {
        Yii::$app->session->addFlash('success', 'Запись успешно сохранена.');
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    } else {
        if (!Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
            $model->loadDefaultValues();
        }
        if ($model->hasErrors()) {
            Yii::$app->getResponse()->setStatusCode(400);
        }
        return $this->render('form', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

P.S. Как выяснилось, не работает в экшнах если они определены через трейт. Если определить экшн прямо в контроллере, то код срабатывает. Почему так?

Comment: Доходит ли до метода? Пробовали дебажить?

Comment: Да, доходит. `$model->hasErrors() == true`

Comment: Yii::$app->response->statusCode = 400; Вроде бы так правильнее...

Comment: Тоже не работает.

Comment: В большинстве случаев значение yii\web\Response::statusCode по умолчанию равно 200. Если и выше указанное не сработало, то нужно выбросить соответствующее HTTP-исключение: throw new \yii\web\BadRequestHttpException;

Comment: Помогло или нет? У меня все работает.

Comment: Я как раз не хотел выбрасывать исключение. Хотел создать такой случай, при котором ошибка валидации вернет ту же форму, но с предупреждениями и с кодом 400, чтобы сработало событие `pjax:error`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причина более чем банальна: виджет Pjax устанавливает статус 200 при вызове.
А поскольку вызывается он в view при рендеринге, установленный в экшне контроллера статус перебивается.